# I deployed my application on heroku successfully. But it does not load the data from database

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express, heroku

I deployed my app succesfully on heroku. But it does not load my data. After research on couple of articles and tutorials, I did not find anywhere how to connect my local postgresql data to heroku addons.

My app works fine locally. When I checked the issue on browser it showed `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432`.

I add Heroku postgres addons and add credentials to my database setup but still does not work. I am totally lost.

**This is my database setup**

```js
const sequelize = require("./node_modules/sequelize");

var con = new sequelize("image", "postgres", "password", {
  host: "localhost", //i think the error comes from here
  dialect: "postgres",

  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  }
});

const Person = con.define("person", {
  image: {
    type: sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  firstname: {
    type: sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  lastname: {
    type: sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  email: {
    type: sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      isEmail: true
    }
  }
});

const Post = con.define("post", {
  title: { type: sequelize.STRING },
  content: { type: sequelize.STRING },
  personid: { type: sequelize.INTEGER, foreignKey: true }
});

const Parent = con.define("parent", {
  father: { type: sequelize.STRING },
  mother: { type: sequelize.STRING },
  personid: { type: sequelize.INTEGER }
});

//con.sync({ force: true });

module.exports = con;
```

**This is my Node js' express server**

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const graphqlHTTP = require("express-graphql");
const schema = require("./schema");
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require("path");

app.use(cors());

app.use(
  "/graphql",
  graphqlHTTP({
    schema,
    pretty: true,
    graphiql: true
  })
);
app.use(express.static("build"));

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "build", index.html));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 8081;
app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`✅  Example app listening on port ${port}!`)
);
```

**I modified my database like this**

```
require("dotenv").config();

const sequelize = require("./node_modules/sequelize");

const con = new sequelize(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
  dialect: "postgres",
  protocol: "postgres",
  dialectOptions: {
    ssl: true
  }
});
```

**Now it works fine on my laptop but it does not work other devices.**

**Here is the link:** https://apask.herokuapp.com/

Comment: because you need to create a db instance in heroku/ or on any other db server and give its url there
instead of localhost!

Comment: Thanks Avinash. Can you please show me the example how to do that. I am really lost.

Comment: You can refer this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql

Answer (score 0):

you need to add environment variables to your app... dotenv, follow the instructions and then set your DATABASE_URL appropriately in your heroku config (it may do that on it's own when you setup postgres, it's a free add on up to 10,000 rows, so add that on and then export and import the database you are using locally into that heroku postgres instance).. you can test it locally by making your DATABASE_URL = localhost and play with it til it works.. your deploy will actually not have the .env file in there so it will take from the heroku config variables

sooo ... instead of your hardcoded localhost you need to do something like process.env.DATABASE_URL in your code and set DATABASE_URL in your .env file locally to test... then your app will pick it up.. if you look at the settings tab in your heroku app, i suspect DATABASE_URL is already there.. once you get it working properly locally which is easier, it'll just work in heroku.. i can help you more as you get closer with code samples

Cheers

Comment: so the heroku version works for you? Is that what you mean? or does it only work when you run locally with local postgres?

Comment: i can't hit your link, you have cors setup from what i can see, or maybe heroku is just not working type thing

Comment: Sorry, I redeploy the app. But seems like still does not work :(.
Here is the new link: https://apask.herokuapp.com/

Comment: About your question's answer:
Heroku version works for me. When I tired other device it does not now show anything just my blank screen.

Comment: ok. so what are your cors settings in your heroku env variables? you are clearly getting closer to getting rolling so not far now

Comment: hmm. I don't know :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Greg. You have been helping me a lot.

Comment: you need to add papertrail (free add on) if you haven't already... then when you hit your app as long as you are logging, you'll see what the error is.. or perhaps it already errors out during deploy.. post that error in here... when i look at your browser error above though, it does not look to me like you associated a heroku postgres add on to your application.... Heroku cannot hit your local database instance... it must have it's own

Comment: Then you should add the solution here to help others that have similar problems!! Cheers

Comment: Ok. I will do it asap